# Obter IMEI usando o ionic 2

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic2, app-hibrido

Estou começando agora a usar o ionic, e gostaria de saber como obter o número de imei do aparelho usando o ionic 2.

Tentei [esse](https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-imei), porém não entendi como instalar o plugin

Answer (score 0):

Ionic oferece acesso a algumas informações do dispositivo em que roda, por exemplo: modelo do aparelho, versão do sistema operacional, número de serial e uuid.

No terminal, dentro da pasta do projeto, é necessário executar os seguintes comandos:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
npm install --save @ionic-native/device
```

No seu arquivo .ts, use da seguinte maneira:

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

constructor(private device: Device) {}

getImei(){ 
   console.log(this.device.uuid);
}
```